# Best method of including an abstract in a latex 'book'?

Tags: latex, abstract, tex, typesetting

I've been looking for the answer to this question for a while now but can't seem to find it, so I'm hoping someone on here can help me.

I'm writing up a thesis in Latex, and really like the \frontmatter, \mainmatter and \backmatter ability when using the "book" environment. However I need to add an abstract and the \begin{abstract} environment is undefined when creating a "book". If I change to a "report" however, I lose the functionality of the *matter terms.

So what I really need to know is: is there a simple method of including an abstract in a "book" and have it formatted the same as it would be in a "report"? (i.e. centered vertically and horizontally  with an 'abstract' heading)

Thanks for any help! First post on stackoverflow after reading for months!

---

Thanks to Jacob for the help. The code below is the closest I could get without making any drastic changes. If someone has a more 'proper' method of implementing this I'd be glad to hear it. ;)

```
\chapter*{\centering \begin{normalsize}Abstract\end{normalsize}}
\begin{quotation}
\noindent % abstract text
\end{quotation}
\clearpage
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
\chapter*{Abstract}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abstract}
```

Best I could come up with.

You can center it with

```
\chapter*{\centering Abstract}
```

Comment: Thanks! Ended up using something to this effect alright. Had to expand it a little, and so have included it in the edited section. Also, i'm not sure the abstract is supposed to be included in any TOC? Either way, thanks for your help!

Comment: @olan - Thanks! Yeah, if you want to include it, now you know how :) Also, could you tell me why you're using `book` and not `report`? Just curious

Comment: I've everything already formatted with the \frontmatter and \backmatter which sorts out all the page numbers and keeps the PDF structure nice and organised. Although judging from the lack of documentation about abstracts in LaTeX books i can't help but feel i'm doing something very wrong!

Answer (score 3):

I recommend the memoir environment. It is [very well documented](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memman.pdf) and AFAIR it provides all features you need.

Comment: indeed it is, but it would require me to change too much of the latex code I have at the minute. In particular it seems to be incompatible with the float and fancyhdr packages, both of which I have implemented, but I'm sure it offers alternatives... I'm just being lazy! 

Thanks for the suggestion though, will keep it in mind for my next project.

Comment: This is absolutely the right answer. Memoir has changed my LiFe; it has repaid the (not inconsiderable, but not as heavy as it might be) learning time many times over.

Comment: memoir has more powerful stuff than fancyhdr built in. It takes some getting used to, it's true...